# Returning an object from another function reuturns as undefined() in the caller

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i'm attempting to do something fairly simple: call a function which uses jquery to return a bunch of values from a page and then return that in the form of an object. Setting that return to a variable in the calling function. Except that comes back as `undefined()`. Notice that it isn't actually undefined but an undefined function? Here's my code:

```
var getValues = function(){
      //jquery to get the values and set them to variables here.....
      //....
      //....

      var foo = {totalPayment: totalPaymentShared, nameVal: name, conditions: conditionsArray};
      console.log(JSON.stringify(foo));

      return foo;
  };
```

Assume the values in the object are all set properly. Here's the result of the console.log:
`{"totalPayment":"123","nameVal":"John Smith","conditions":[2,3]}`

Here's the code for the caller:

```
var addValuesToNewObject = function(){
       var values = getValues();
       console.log(values);
       console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
       var sharedConfig = new customObject();
       sharedConfig.payment = values.totalPayment;
       sharedConfig.name = values.nameVal;
       sharedConfig.paidOnCondition = values.conditions;
       sharedConfig.hasBeenAdded = true;
       sharedConfig.action = 1;
```

If I hover over `values` in the firefox debugger it shows as `undefined()`. Console logging it shows the object as it should be. console logging `values.totalPayment` returns undefined. Hoping a javascript expert can fill me in on what's happening here. I believe the functionality is properly working, but I'm still concerned as to what is actually being returned from this function.

NOTE: as i mentioned, the `sharedConfig` object properly gets its values from the values object...so it's not that the code doesn't work, it's that debugging is impossible when values is shows as `undefined()`. Could it have to do with the functions being function expressions?

Comment: Where exactly are the variables being set on the `foo` coming from?

Comment: just jquery. I can confirm in the debugger that the variables are set properly to strings and as you can see in the console log. They are set where I put that comment in `getValues()` for example: `var name = $('#custom-name').val();`

Comment: have you confirmed this isn't a bug with the FireFox immediate browser?  Can you please create a jsfiddle that depicts this issue.

Comment: I'll upvote the issue as I'm interested in the problem, but can you please create a jsfiddle that'll reproduce this issue for us to investigate?

Comment: Cannot reproduce in chrome. Either chrome is handling bad code somewhere, or it is a firefox developer edition debugger bug.

Comment: hi, I was reading your situation and it seems really weird and I tried it in firebug's debugger and it shows correct values on hover, are you still having this issue?

Comment: I think when you're referencing a "class" with properties in an each, firefox can't figure out the value on hover. Just a firefox bug i guess